# EMFILE Error in express node.js because of too many open TCP connection

Tags: node.js, express, keep-alive, lsof

I am running my node.js express app, which is NOT behind any nginx layer.
I am facing an EMFILE Error server crash problem, every couple of days.

After some debugging, i am able to narrow down the problem to too much open TCP connections for my app.

The Number of Open TCP Connections are consistently increasing for the app. i used `lsof` with process pid for this

I have tried putting in `app.use(timeout(30000));`
using the `'connect-timeout'` middleware for express. But the TCP connections are still increasing. Should it get flushed after 30 sec timeout.

Any help in this regard will be very helpful.

PS: my express app by default is sending 
`Connection: keep-alive` header in the response.

Could this be the source of problem? and what will be the resolution.

Thanks

Comment: What type of client is your server being used by? I would not expect browsers to keep connections open, especially not for extended periods of time. What does your server do? Does it connect to some external resource (database, another HTTP server) itself?

Comment: Yes, it is for browsers. it is web application, it connects to mongodb using node mongoose, but does not connect with other http server. here is a link for the app: http://hellotars.com/convBot/demos/vanitycube/

Comment: I don't see any connections that remain open (although I only took a glance). Can you add some of the lsof output to your question? Also, what does `ulimit -n` (run as the user that also runs the app server) return?

Comment: Here is the lsof greped over process id: http://pastebin.com/KsC0DiXL

ulimit -n says 99999

Comment: lsof line count in this dump is 258, because i recently restarted the server, but after a couple of hours of normal traffic, this number increases to 2000. As a temp fix, i am running a cron-job to restart the server every 12 hours, but i don't want to do that.

Comment: 2000 doesn't sound like a whole lot, and it doesn't make sense that you'd get an `EMFILE` when ulimit is set to 99999. Also, it looks like the connection is only one-way: from your VPS to the client, but not the other way around (unless the pastebin data is incomplete). That's unexpected, as a connection would need two sides.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101077/discussion-between-vinit-and-robertklep).

Comment: What i don't understand, is why this value is increasing. shouldn't it increase and go back to very low value, when their is no traffic on the site.

Comment: Yes, you would expect that. But since it seems that only one half of the TCP connections are being shown in the `lsof` output, there might be something else going on.